# "Layout Inflator " and "Fragment Layout" in android

Tags: android

Plz explain difference between functionality of "Layout Inflator " and "Fragment Layout" in android and which are best user case scenario for these two.

Comment: Layout inflator will parse a XML layout and return View object. FragmentLayout is a kind of View.

Answer (score 0):

Layoutinflator and Frame layout are 2 different concept. Layoutinflator  is used to insansiate views to a view where as frame layout is viewgroup that can hold single item at a time.

For more details
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

```
**Layout Inflator:**

 - Layout inflator is used to inflate UI(our desire layout xml). It is
   similar to setContentView(view)

   It can be replace setContentView.

   It will be handy in fragments, since We are not able to use
   setContentView in fragments.

   We can use inflator in both activity and fragments. e.g. If you want
   to customize dialog alert or pop up etc..

**FrameLayout**

 - FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
   a single item.

   FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it
   can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to
   different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

   FrameLayout is designed to display single item. It can be handy in
   fragments , since it holds single item.
```

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/6325805/writingforanroidoid has mentioned, layoutinflater and framelayout are two different concepts.

But I guess the guys asks about fragmentlayout and not framelayout. To my knowledge, there is no entity by that name in Android. However, when you use a fragment inside an activity, the fragment has to define it's layout(and the activity just could include the fragment) and may be that's what is fragment layout.